# Lex reports error because of ambiguous priority

Tags: lex

```
identifier [\._a-zA-Z0-9\/]+
comment "//"

<*>{comment}  {
    cout<<"Comment\n";
  char c;
  while((c= yyinput()) != '\n')
    {
    }
}

<INITIAL>{s}{e}{t} {
   BEGIN(SAMPLE_STATE);
   return SET;
}

<SAMPLE_STATE>{identifier} {
    strncpy(yylval.str, yytext,1023);
    yylval.str[1023] = '\0';
  return IDENTIFIER;
}
```

In the above lex code, there is no error when "// set name" is parsed. Please notice the space after "//" in the sentence parsed. However, when "//set name" is parsed, there is an error reported. I believe it has something to do with the forward slash that appears in both identifier and comment. Could you point to where I am going wrong? Thanks.

The error is caught by yyerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lex always matches the longest match in any context.  So when the input is `//set`, that will match an `{identifier}` pattern.  Since you never set the lex state to anything other than `SAMPLE_STATE` in your above code, it's likely that you hit this problem when you are in state `SAMPLE_STATE`, so the lexer just returns it as an identifier, rather than matching the `{comment}` rule and skipping the rest of the line.

There are a number of ways to avoid the problem.  You could have the `{comment}` rule match the rest of the line in the pattern:

```
<*>"//".*   {
    cout << "Comment\n"; }
```

Note that with this, you don't need the explicit reading of the rest of the line.

Alternately, you could disallow multiple consecutive `/` characters in an identifer:

```
identifier (/?[._a-zA-Z0-9])*/?
```